# How to measure network traffic on a port

Tags: networking, wireshark, fiddler

I am using fiddler to monitor what is going on.  Though I cant see total traffic over time for a session.

Any tools that can do that easily
(If I could export the statistics to a spreadsheet from Fiddler it would be OK).

Windows/Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

**Edit:**

"Wireshark is a network packet analyzer. A network packet analyzer will try to capture network packets and tries to display that packet data as detailed as possible."

Have a look at the [documentation](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/), specifically [Capture Filters](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters) to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I have (I couldn't see exactly how to do this, and also it wasn't so easy to set it up in general)

Comment: @InginiteLurker please give a little more info on the program and what exactly it does and how one can get some help.

Comment: Fiddler is about the same as Wireshark.  Just suggesting other network tools is not so useful, but of course Wireshark is one of the main ones and could be better/easier than Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, try the combination of [Microsoft Visual Round Trip Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=119f3477-dced-41e3-a0e7-d8b5cae893a3&displaylang=en) and [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en).

Comment: This looks quite web-oriented.Any reason to think it beats Wireshark/Fiddler?  I am mostly looking at ports, and I can easily more them.  For example I throttle with  iprelay -b 1000000 8082:localhost:8080

Comment: Well, fiddler is a tool for http, so I though this might be a good match.  I haven't used wireshark, so I can't offer a comparison.  Another thing you might want to look into are the developer tools built into Chrome.